# Manual searching is not working using with NSOBJECT

Tags: ios, swift

my application will crashed when I tried this code using `NSObject`

```
 var preda = NSPredicate(format: "ClientName contains[c] %@", strTemp)
  aryClientConvrsationList = (objSearchresult as NSArray).filtered(using: preda) as! [PIClientConversationList]
  print(aryClientConvrsationList)
  self.tableviewSupport.reloadData()
```

Comment: can you show the error

Comment: `as! [PIClientConversationList]` is bad, also what is inside: `strTemp` ?

Comment: @Andrea Mugnaini strTemp have textfield value

Comment: @ Rahul Dasgupta Error is "'[<PureTeamManager.PIClientConversationList 0x6040002cd740> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ClientName.'"

Comment: might you print it? before to enter in the `NSPredicate`. Also might you post the definition of `PIClientConversationList` ?

Comment: @Andrea Mugnain strTemp have print fine but i got error '[<PureTeamManager.PIClientConversationList 0x6040002cd740> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ClientName.'

Comment: which is the type of `ClientName` ?

Comment: @Andrea Mugnain ClientName is in string type

Comment: Ok, modify it with NSString, try again

Comment: @Andrea Mugnain ok

Comment: @Andrea Mugnaini i set NSString but will shows same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check whether

```
 (objSearchresult as NSArray).filtered(using: preda) as! [PIClientConversationList]
```

actually returns [PIClientConversationList]

Answer (score 0):

If your model object is not subclass of NSObject you cannot use NSPredicate with it.

NSPredicate to evaluate if your object pass a test use @objc valueForKey: method. Swift types do not implement this method by default.

You can **workaround** this by implementing this method in your model class:

```
@objc func value(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
    if key == "ClientName" {
        return ClientName
    }
    fatalError()
}
```